# Способы ожидания завершения анимации

Tags: .net, selenium, nunit

Нужна помощь в реализации ожидания завершения анимации, перед выполнением следующего шага в автотесте.
Как я понял, иногда из за этого падает тест так как клик производится в неправильное место.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Единственное, что придумал для решения это использовать Thread.Sleep(), но это не хорошая практика. Думал о использовать JS но не нашел какой код можно использовать.
Подскажите как можно проверить завершение анимации?

Comment: можешь ускорить анимацию, подредактировав ее в CSS (время на ноль) и подождать 50-100 миллисекунд на всякий случай

Comment: можно просто пустой css страничке подкинуть (если тебе важен функционал, а не стиль, естесственно)

Comment: @dgzargo Поменять ничего не могу. Нужно как то протестировать в состоянии которое есть.

Comment: посмотри [на эту картинку](https://imgur.com/a/LRLcqJn): взял и удалил стили у stackoverflow. и даже комент после этого отправил!))

Comment: в реальности все работает. у тебя какие-то внутренние ограничения?

Comment: @dgzargo удалять всюду не вариант, есть другие тесты с другими окнами, где тоже иногда происходит падение из за загрузки анимации. Поэтому надо что то придумать для проверки загрузки страницы.